# How can I get gedit ready for programming in Ruby and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: programming, gedit, ruby, rails, unicode-entry

I'd like to know which `gedit` plugins I could install to make programming for Ruby and Ruby on Rails easier?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

simply

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-on-rails/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate
```

and activate the plugins you want from options menu. It will activate sintax highlighting for erb files and many snippets for RoR developing.

Comment: Thank You! The autoindenting feature doesn't work! #fail

Comment: @Victor, `gedit` doesn't do anything like auto-indenting for any languages as far as I know. You'd an IDE for that.

Comment: Auto indent won't work, unless you enable Smart Indent plugin in Gedit settings.

Answer (score 7):

Some more hints can be found here: https://rbjl.janlelis.com/22-rubybuntu-4-make-gedit-better-than-any-ide. Some commands for the "external commands" plugin (e.g. "run in irb") can be found in this post: https://rbjl.janlelis.com/23-gedit-external-tools-ruby-helpers-git-integration-and-more

**2020 Update:** As Crimbo noted, this might be outdated now...

Comment: ...though the post is old now, it needs updating. Some of the plugins aren't in Gedit v3 and the Ruby irb command external tool you supply doesn't keep the terminal open (on Linux) for example. Keep up the good work though - Be great if you could update it.